# Java - Download piece of webpage

Tags: java, url

Recently I heard someone saying that it is possible to download a "piece" of a webpage and avoid downloading the entire webpage. For example, I have to download a webpage (http://someurl.com) to parse it and extract some information. Is there any way of only downloading a "piece" of it, instead of the whole webpage?

Regards.-

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a piece? Just the html? What exactly?

Comment: If they have rest end points, you can call the appropriate endpoint to get the data you want.

Comment: Are you asking about [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), perhaps?

Comment: @Austin Yes, a "piece" would be part of the HTML. Only some divs. I am almost sure it is not possible, but someone is arguing with that premise and I just want to be sure there isn't a trick somewhere to do that,

Comment: @Cypher No, assume you have a desktop application and you need to download a HTML to parse it and extract information. But downloading the complete HTML is not so efficient.

Comment: How is downloading the HTML not efficient? It's probably the smallest (by far) part of the webpage.

Comment: I think in most cases, it really won't make any difference in efficiency if you download the entire page. It would only have the HTML markup and none of the pictures/CSS/Javascript/whatever files unless you make new requests for these items.

Comment: @DarkSquirtings Yes, but it is not the same to download 100KB of a webpage to 2KB of the divs you only need. If you repeat this process a hundred times, you will see some efficiency problems.

Comment: Hey people, why you down vote my question and then post some answers?! The fact you don't know the answer does not mean it is a bad question!

Comment: The fact that it's a bad question makes it a bad question. There isn't enough information in it to give an answer other than the one I gave below. Are you downloading the same page over and over to see if anything changes? Is this a webpage you have control over, or a third party's? Is this program intended to mass scan pages from all over the place? Do you know the format of the page you're downloading ahead of time? We can't tell you how to do something when you haven't actually told us what you want to do.

Comment: @DarkSquirtings Those are obvious questions. If you write some code to parse a webpage is because you want to _automate_ the load of "changes" in it, otherwise why would someone want to code an HTML download and parsing?

Comment: So you're complaining about us not giving you answers... and you can't even be arsed to answer the questions we need answers to before answering your question, because obviously we should know what you're trying to do without actually telling us first.

Comment: @DarkSquirtings I am not complaining for not receiving the answers, I am complaining because you people are down voting the question!. And of course it is obvious, otherwise please do tell me another case where you are going to write a download and parsing webpage routine if it is a static webpage? Your argument makes no sense. The question is simple, download webpage, parse webpage, get data. And obviously I am catching variations in the page.

Comment: Downvoted AND flagged, since even after being asked to clarify and given specific prompts on which parts to explain you've refused to do so.

Comment: @DarkSquirtings Good. Thanks for giving me the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Start downloading the page as normal (open a socket, contact the server, request the page, etc.), then stop the operation after you receive the first 20 bytes of data.

Boom, part of a webpage. You won't be able to parse anything, but how you're planning on doing that with only part of the webpage anyway is unclear from your question.

Comment: Yes, that could do the trick. The thing is that the webpage is dynamic, the data is constantly changing its place. Besides the parsing may fail if the HTML is not fully formed now that I see it.

Comment: You COULD parse the 20 bytes, but I doubt it would be particularly useful.  lol.  This seems like an odd question to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is possible confusion with the questioning just now because of an unfortunate lack of specificity. Let's define it in terms of a single URL which references a single resource accessible through HTTP/1.1. When in doubt let's go to a [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). From source: HTTP/1.1 is a revision of the original HTTP (HTTP/1.0). In HTTP/1.0 a separate connection to the same server is made for every resource request. HTTP/1.1 can reuse a connection multiple times to download images, scripts, stylesheets, etc after the page has been delivered. HTTP/1.1 communications therefore experience less latency as the establishment of TCP connections presents considerable overhead.

HTTP defines methods (sometimes referred to as verbs) to indicate the desired action to be performed on the identified resource. What this resource represents, whether pre-existing data or data that is generated dynamically, depends on the implementation of the server. Often, the resource corresponds to a file or the output of an executable residing on the server. The HTTP/1.0 specification[11] defined the GET, POST and HEAD methods and the HTTP/1.1 specification[12] added 5 new methods: OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, TRACE and CONNECT. By being specified in these documents their semantics are well known and can be depended upon. Any client can use any method and the server can be configured to support any combination of methods. If a method is unknown to an intermediate it will be treated as an unsafe and non-idempotent method. There is no limit to the number of methods that can be defined and this allows for future methods to be specified without breaking existing infrastructure. For example, WebDAV defined 7 new methods and RFC 5789 specified the PATCH method.

We can ask for the *head* alone or ask for the body, but if we are hitting a resource, other than the *head* method I know of no way to ask for part of the resource. So the answer would be *NO* unless the question allows for *head* for a single http resource. N.B. an image or a script would be accessible as *separate* resources.